# How to print json array in excel4node

Tags: node.js, excel4node

I have to print an excel with 10000 rows. There is any way to bulk print a json array using excel4node?.

e.g.: Mongodb insertMany operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a gist from the npm author. It seems is not possible already to do it

https://gist.github.com/natergj/46bc984855c4478f50d890353727514f

This is the example:

```
const xl = require('excel4node');

// Create workbook and add worksheet
const wb = new xl.Workbook();
const ws = wb.addWorksheet('Data', {
  disableRowSpansOptimization: true,
});

// Generate some fake data for testing
const data = [];
const rowCount = 50000;
let row = 1;
while (row <= rowCount) {
  data.push({
    zone_name: `zone_name_${row}`,
    circle_name: `circle_name_${row}`,
    div_town_name: `div_town_name_${row}`,
    tender_name: `tender_name_${row}`,
    tkc_name: `tkc_name_${row}`,
    work_name: `work_name_${row}`,
    material_name: `material_name_${row}`,
    insert_dttm: new Date(),
    app_fname: `app_fname_${row}`,
    ins_fname: `ins_fname_${row}`,
  });
  row += 1;
}

const startRow = 4;
// Add data to worksheet
if (data.length) {
  data.forEach((item, i) => {
    const currentRow = i + startRow;
    const newtarget = 'newtarget';
    const newprogress = 'newprogress';

    ws.cell(currentRow, 1).number(i).style({
      alignment: {
        vertical: ['center'],
        horizontal: ['left']
      },
      font: {
        color: '000000',
        size: 12
      },
      border: {
        bottom: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        right: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        left: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        top: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        }
      }
    });
    ws.cell(currentRow, 2).string(item.zone_name).style({
      alignment: {
        vertical: ['center'],
        horizontal: ['left']
      },
      font: {
        color: '000000',
        size: 12
      },
      border: {
        bottom: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        right: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        left: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        top: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        }
      }
    });
    ws.cell(currentRow, 3).string(item.circle_name).style({
      alignment: {
        vertical: ['center'],
        horizontal: ['left']
      },
      font: {
        color: '000000',
        size: 12
      },
      border: {
        bottom: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        right: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        left: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        top: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        }
      }
    });
    ws.cell(currentRow, 4).string(item.div_town_name).style({
      alignment: {
        vertical: ['center'],
        horizontal: ['left']
      },
      font: {
        color: '000000',
        size: 12
      },
      border: {
        bottom: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        right: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        left: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        top: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        }
      }
    });
    ws.cell(currentRow, 5).string(item.tender_name).style({
      alignment: {
        vertical: ['center'],
        horizontal: ['left']
      },
      font: {
        color: '000000',
        size: 12
      },
      border: {
        bottom: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        right: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        left: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        top: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        }
      }
    });
    ws.cell(currentRow, 6).string(item.tkc_name).style({
      alignment: {
        vertical: ['center'],
        horizontal: ['left']
      },
      font: {
        color: '000000',
        size: 12
      },
      border: {
        bottom: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        right: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        left: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        top: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        }
      }
    });
    ws.cell(currentRow, 7).string(item.work_name).style({
      alignment: {
        vertical: ['center'],
        horizontal: ['left']
      },
      font: {
        color: '000000',
        size: 12
      },
      border: {
        bottom: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        right: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        left: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        top: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        }
      }
    });
    ws.cell(currentRow, 8).string(item.material_name).style({
      alignment: {
        vertical: ['center'],
        horizontal: ['left']
      },
      font: {
        color: '000000',
        size: 12
      },
      border: {
        bottom: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        right: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        left: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        top: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        }
      }
    });
    ws.cell(currentRow, 9).string(newtarget).style({
      alignment: {
        vertical: ['center'],
        horizontal: ['left']
      },
      font: {
        color: '000000',
        size: 12
      },
      border: {
        bottom: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        right: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        left: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        top: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        }
      }
    });
    ws.cell(currentRow, 10).string(newprogress).style({
      alignment: {
        vertical: ['center'],
        horizontal: ['left']
      },
      font: {
        color: '000000',
        size: 12
      },
      border: {
        bottom: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        right: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        left: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        top: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        }
      }
    });
    ws.cell(currentRow, 11).date(item.insert_dttm).style({
      alignment: {
        vertical: ['center'],
        horizontal: ['left']
      },
      font: {
        color: '000000',
        size: 12
      },
      border: {
        bottom: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        right: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        left: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        top: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        }
      }
    });
    ws.cell(currentRow, 12).string(item.app_fname).style({
      alignment: {
        vertical: ['center'],
        horizontal: ['left']
      },
      font: {
        color: '000000',
        size: 12
      },
      border: {
        bottom: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        right: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        left: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        top: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        }
      }
    });
    ws.cell(currentRow, 13).string(item.ins_fname).style({
      alignment: {
        vertical: ['center'],
        horizontal: ['left']
      },
      font: {
        color: '000000',
        size: 12
      },
      border: {
        bottom: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        right: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        left: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        },
        top: {
          style: 'thin',
          color: '000000'
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

// Write workbook once all data has been added to worksheet
wb.write('Overall_Progress_Report.xlsx');
```

As you can see, he iterates json array.

Answer (score 1):

For that you can make a function that takes json as input and iterate over it inside of the function.
Because of that you will be able to see your operation as single one if that’s what you wanted.

Comment: Sorry that's not what I really want. I know I can do it iterating the array but I would like to know if there is any possibility of printing all in one operation. Like mongodb updateMany operation.